# compare n^log log n with c^n and n^k

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

What is the relation in terms of asymptotic analysis, between n^log log n and $c^n$,$n^k$ ?
how can find relation between such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write each in terms of the function $\exp$.

Comment: i converted each of them as $e^(log(logn))*ln n ,   e^k*ln n,   e^n ln c

Comment: OK, so how do these compare asymptotically, $\log(\log n) \log n$, $k \log n$, $n \log c$?

Comment: $O(k log n) = O(log(log n)log n =O(n log c)$ am i right?

Comment: No.  $k \log(n) = O(\log(\log n) \log n)$ but $\log(\log(n) \log n$ is not $O(k \log(n))$.  Similarly
$\log(\log n) \log(n) = O(n \log c)$ (if $\log c > 0$), but not vice versa.

Comment: i meant the same, dint know how to show subset. Thank's a lot.

Comment: But i have one more question. I could look at these and infer the asymptotic relations. But what if i get functions which are hard to infer just by looking. I understood we have to use limits. Can you point me to a source where i can get to know how to use them in finding asymptotic relations?